# How to enable to read other uid data in realtime firebase rule?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a customer app that needs to know whether a shop is open or not. So the customer app needs access shop uid data to know is shop open or not? How can I achieve this using firebase rule ? And the owner(shop) of this can also change his `setShopOnOff:true` value.

```
users
  SHOPID--rOOXXXoyCggX2
    distributorId:"ASSSSASPbkHX2"
    email:"fSSASA@g.com"
    setShopOnOff:true
  CUSTOMERUID--fXXX5EjEVksOr53
    acquired:true
    customer:true
    email : "csddd@g.com"
    franchiseId : "SHOPID--rOOXXXoyCggX2"
    income
    myAccount
```

and my current rules look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {  
      "$uid": {
        "setShopOnOff": { // not getting any data
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid", // tried true
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
                                        },
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        
                    },
                    },
    "orders": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
                    },
                },
        }
  }
```

After fetching `franchiseId` from `CUSTOMERUID--fXXX5EjEVksOr53` I am trying to get data from diffrent uid `SHOPID--rOOXXXoyCggX2` like below

```
 const userdata = ref(db, `/users/${user1.uid}`);
    await onValue(userdata, (snapshot) => {
      grabbedData.push(snapshot.val());
     
      setShowloading(false);
      if (grabbedData) {
        Object.keys(grabbedData).map(function (key) {
          let x = grabbedData[key];
          if (x) {
            if (x.customer) {
              setCustomer(true);
              franchiseId1 = x.franchiseId;
              // setFranchiseId(franchiseId);
              if (x.myAccount) {
                ShopName = x.myAccount.shopName;
                cityName = x.myAccount.city;
                setShopName(ShopName);
                setCity(cityName);

                if (franchiseId1) {
                  const getFranchiseIdData = ref(db, `/users/${franchiseId1}`);
                  onValue(getFranchiseIdData, (snapshot1) => {
                    franchiseIddata.push(snapshot1.val());
                    console.log(snapshot1.val());
                    setIsShopOpen(franchiseIddata[0].setShopOnOff);
                  });
                }
              }
            } else {
              setCustomer(false);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Rules are quite meaningless on their own. Can you edit your question to show the code that you use against these rules, and explain what doesn't work about that (i.e. what *is* allowed that shouldn't be, or vice versa).

Comment: I added the code I diddn,t get {snapshot1} value under "if (franchiseId1)" block I think it is unable to access ref path. It works fine when we allow no security rules.

Comment: What are the values of `user1.uid` and of `franchiseId1` in your code? Please `console.log` them just before using them in a call to the database API, and edit your question to include the updated code and its output.

Comment: The `user1.uid` is `CUSTOMERUID--fXXX5EjEVksOr53`and `franchiseId1 ` is  `SHOPID--rOOXXXoyCggX2`

Comment: Please `console.log` them just before using them in a call to the database API, and edit your question to include the updated code and its output. The reason I ask for that specifically is that it rules out mistakes you might make in passing/looking up those values.